# Как перемещать контрол по форме?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как перемещать какой-нибудь контрол по форме так, как в конструкторе ? Например, `tablelayoutpanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из кода можно также менять свойства компонента как и из конструктора

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Location.X (Y)
```

Также вам поможет [эта статья](http://csharpcoding.org/peremeshhenie-knopki-po-forme/).

Comment: Хм, так как я понял программно установить положение контрола, а как мне мышкой взять и тягать контрол?

Comment: @Кирилл Кирьянчиков Не так понял вопрос. Тогда вот [это](http://csharpcoding.org/peremeshhenie-knopki-po-forme/) прочитайте, должно помочь.

Comment: Полезная статья, спасибо!